# Entity Framework: How to map the columns to the database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

On of my model's properties needs to be from a custom type. This custom type has two properties [ID, TextToShow]. What I want is to save only the value of ID of the custom type in the database. The other value which is TextToShow is used only when retrieving from database.

I am using EF6,VS2015 and C# connected to SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Entity Framework to ignore a column in the database, use the `NotMapped` attribute on your model's property.

```
class Example {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string TextToShow { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to ignore the whole value of the property. As I mentioned above that the property is of a custom object called DualItem that has two fields: ID and TextToShow. What I want is to save the value of ID and ignore the value of TextToShow because it is going to be assigned manually when retrieving from  the database. Do you think of any solution? 
Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Do you only update `TextToShow` once, or something?

Comment: Here is the think. I am developing a bilingual app.  Let us say that I have a GENDER column. In the programming interface I two options [male =0 , female =1] but the text that appears to the user it is retrieved from another table depending on his/her language preferences. 

So I don't store TextToShow in the database since it is always changing. 
Will try the method you mentioned and will get back to you. 
Thnaks

Comment: I tried that, the only problem I have is that EF creates a table for DualItem ID values instead of saving it only in the Gender column.

Comment: Fixed:

1) I changed the name of ID field to something else so that EF to recognize it as a key.
2) Marked TextToShow as [NotMapped] as you suggested. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Found:**
1) I changed the name of ID field to something else so that EF to recognize it as a key.

2) Marked TextToShow as [NotMapped]

The result: Only the value of ID field [which have been renamed] is being stored in the database.

*

> Will keep this conversation open for anyone who face the same problem

  *

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, what you need is a [Complex Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj680147.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#What) It should be easy to set up with EF Designer. Or you can check [this blog post by Brady Holt](http://www.geekytidbits.com/complex-types-entity-framework/) if you're using code first approach.

Once you add complex type mark the field you want to ignore with [NotMapped] attribute

Comment: Yes that was what I am looking for. I marked the fields I didn't to store in the database as [NotMapped] and it worked.